# How to select multiple items from list based of index with Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

lets say I have an array like this:

```
var items = [
 0: {},
 1: {},
 2: {},
 3: {},
 4: {},
 5: {}
]
```

And I know which Items i want to handle since I have figured out their index:

```
List<int> myIndexes = new List<int> { 0, 3, 5};
```

I want to get items `0, 3, 5`

How would I accomplish this with a `LINQ` query?

looking for something like:

```
var myNewItems = items.Something(myIndexes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have a *collection* of indexes, say

```
List<int> myIndexes = new List<int> { 0, 3, 5 };
```

to get corresponging values from `items` we can query these `myIndexes`:

```
var myValues = myIndexes
  .Select(index => items[index])
  .ToList();
```

Comment: This makes sense. I was approaching this from focusing on fetching  from items first rather than doing it the other way arround and iterating from indexes. Thanks alot and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  myIndexes.Select(i=>myNewItems[i]);
```